# Как ТГ боту на python реагировать на новые ответы в опросе?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Делаю телеграм бота на python, aiogram с играми. По идее бот должен отправлять викторину, и писать в консоль "Правильно!" если ответ пользователя верен. Опросы отправляются, а на ответы бот никак не реагирует. Используя официальную документацию aiogram, я сделал следующий код:
Функция отправки викторины:

```
async def quiz(sender_id, question: str, rigth_answer: str, answers: str, explanation: str):
    answers = answers.split(',')
    random.shuffle(answers)
    index_rigth_answer = answers.index(rigth_answer)
    my_quiz = await bot.send_poll(sender_id, question, answers, type='quiz', correct_option_id=index_rigth_answer, explanation=explanation)
    return my_quiz
```

Отправка викторины:

```
elif message.text == ' Викторина по шутерам (Макс. +7 XP)':
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE genre=?', ('race', ))
    test = cur.fetchall()
    random_question = random.choice(test)
    global this_quiz
    this_quiz = await quiz(message.chat.id, f'{i}. {random_question[0]}?', random_question[1], random_question[2], random_question[3])
```

Обработка ответа (не срабатывает):

```
@dp.poll_answer_handler()
async def handle_poll_answer(quiz_answer: PollAnswer):
    print(quiz_answer)
    if this_quiz.poll.correct_option_id == quiz_answer:
        print('Правильно!')
    else:
        print('Неправильно!')
```

А самое интересное, что никаких ошибок нет. Может кто-то подсказать, как сделать правильную обработку ответа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в одном аргументе, при отправке опроса:

```
is_anonymous = False
```

По умолчанию, содержит `True`, и из-за этого не выходило получить информацию про ответ